# leak detected using valgrind when using fopen

Tags: c, valgrind

gcc 4.4.4 c89 valgrind 3.5.0.

I am getting a leak detected when I open file using a file pointer.

```
==17681==    in use at exit: 352 bytes in 1 blocks
==17681==    total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 352 bytes allocated
==17681== 
==17681==    352 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==17681==    at 0x4005BDC: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:195)
==17681==    by 0xAAD67E: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:76)
==17681==    by 0xAAD74B: fopen@@GLIBC_2.1 (iofopen.c:107)
```

The code line it is pointing to is this fopen:

```
FILE *fp = NULL;
fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
if(fp == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file [ %s ]\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}
```

Could it be that the fopen function is allocating memory and not freeing it? How can I free this memory?

Many thank for any suggestions,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't fclose your FILE*.

Comment: You **do not** call `free` on a `FILE *`. You call `fclose`.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same error despite using `fclose`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem

I solved it with a fflush()

```
// Stream needs to be flushed before closing
fflush ( fp);

fclose( fp);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess it'll free it if you call `fclose` on the file.